# C# auto check when clicking on listview's label

Tags: c#

[image]I used to listview with CheckBoxs property set to true. I find that it too difficult to user to click on actual checkbox instead of both clicking on actual checkbox and its label.

Could you tell me how can I enable check when clicking on the listview's label.
Please help!!!

Comment: clarify? either by editing your text or inserting image/code ...

Comment: what I want to do is when user click on the label the actual checkbox check too.

Comment: isn't the default `CheckBox` control exactly like what you try to do? I mean when you click on its `Text` field you will get it checked/unchecked

Comment: it's the listview with property "CheckBoxs" set to true.  when I click on its text it didn't checked/unchedk

Comment: Your users could DoubleClick to set/unset the Checkboxes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First do consider that when you `check/uncheck` by a mouse click this will seriously get in the way of `selecting/unselecting` items. If you need both I suggest simply telling the users to use a `doubleclick` for checking.

Also: There is a nice UI standard of `checking/unchecking` items with the `space bar`. This is especially nice after selecting a group of items..!

But if you still want to here is an example. It is a bit of a kludge because we need some check to avoid getting in the way of the normal way to hit the `CheckBox`!

(To work with full precision you would have to measure the `CheckBox Rectangle` and check to see if it was hit.. Using a magic pixel distance of 20 seems to work here. Do look into different display style variations! See below!)

```
private void listView1_MouseClick(object sender, MouseEventArgs e)
{
    ListViewItem lvi = listView1.GetItemAt(e.X, e.Y);
    if (e.X > 20) lvi.Checked = !lvi.Checked;
}
```

One way to get a better check is to measure the `CheckBox`:

```
 using System.Windows.Forms.VisualStyles;
 //..
 Size glyph;
 // in the constructor:
 InitializeComponent();
 //..
 using (Graphics G = listView1.CreateGraphics() )
        glyph = CheckBoxRenderer.GetGlyphSize(G, CheckBoxState.CheckedNormal);
```

..and then checking : `if (e.X > glyph.Width)..`.

I don't know if there is a variable offset of the checkbox from the left side; it looks like `1 pixel`. But there seems to be a gap between the box and the text area anyway..

Comment: You can use lvi.GetBounds(ItemBoundsPortion.Label) to get the bounding rectangle of the label and then check whether the mouse click was in that area.